# Creating a loop to run a statistical test

Tags: r, loops, statistics, p-value

I need to run a statistical test and compute p_hat_6, using N = 10 samples each of size n = 10 from X ∼ uniform(0, 14). Here is my original loop to calculate p_hat at mu=6:

```
pvalue <- rep(0,10)
reject <- 0
alpha <- 0.05
N <- 10

for (n in seq_along(pvalue)){
  pvalue[n] <- wilcox.test(runif(10,0,14), mu=6)$p.value
  reject[n] <- ifelse(pvalue[n] > alpha,0,1)
}

p_hat_6 <- (sum(reject))/N
p_hat_6
```

Using the same N and n, I need to repeat it 5 more times with the following changes:

```
(1) Data from X ∼ uniform(0, 16) and compute p_hat_7 (mu=7)
(2) Data from X ∼ uniform(0, 18) and compute p_hat_8 (mu=8)
(3) Data from X ∼ uniform(0, 20) and compute p_hat_9 (mu=9)
(4) Data from X ∼ uniform(0, 22) and compute p_hat_10 (mu=10)
(5) Data from X ∼ uniform(0, 24) and compute p_hat_11 (mu=11)
```

How do I loop through as the intervals increase by 2 each time and mu increase by 1 each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a function

```
fun1 <- function(N, pvalue, reject, max_val, mu_val) {
  for (n in seq_along(pvalue)){
    pvalue[n] <- wilcox.test(runif(N ,0, max_val), mu=mu_val)$p.value
     reject[n] <- ifelse(pvalue[n] > alpha,0,1)
     }

   p_hat_6 <- (sum(reject))/N
   return(p_hat_6)
   }
```

and use that in `Map`

```
Map(fun1, max_val = seq(14, 24, by = 2), mu_val = 6:11,
       MoreArgs = list(N = 10, pvalue = pvalue, reject = reject))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 0.2

[[3]]
[1] 0.2

[[4]]
[1] 0

[[5]]
[1] 0.1

[[6]]
[1] 0.2
```

---

Or create an outer loop around the function

```
mu_val <- 6:11
max_val <- seq(14, 24, by = 2)
out <- numeric(length(mu_val))
for(i in seq_along(mu_val)) {
    out[i] <- fun1(N = 10, pvalue = pvalue, 
      reject = reject, max_val = max_val[i], mu_val = mu_val[i])
}

out
[1] 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.1 0.3 0.0
```

#### data

```
N <- 10
pvalue <- rep(0, N)
reject <- rep(0, N)
alpha <- 0.05
```

Comment: for the Map function, why it needs to put "MoreArgs = list(.....)", why does those need to be in a list?

Comment: @JakeParker  The arguments that were changing were used as input i.e. `max_val = seq(14, 24, by = 2), mu_val = 6:11` and the ones that are constants I place it in `MoreArgs`.  You may also use that as regular arguments, if the length is 1, then it gets recycled.  The main purpose is to make a distinction between the variable part of hte arguments and the fixed ones - ie. not changing for each loop

Comment: @JakeParker Regarding why it needs to be a list is because each `list` element is considered as a unit and `list` can hold multiple types where as if you pass vector, there can be only a single type

Comment: for the Map output, how do I turn it back into a vector? I tried unlist, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @JakeParker Just `unlist` the `Map` and it will be a vector

Comment: @JakeParker Not clear why you are not getting a vector - `out <- Map(fun1, max_val = seq(14, 24, by = 2), mu_val = 6:11,
       MoreArgs = list(N = 10, pvalue = pvalue, reject = reject))   

> unlist(out)
[1] 0.5 0.0 0.0 0.1 0.0 0.1`